# Inteliij Idea 12 - Maven SNAPSHOT Dependecies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've faced strange error in IDEA 12 while I was working with Maven project.

I imported project successfully. But IDEA can't upload some SNAPSHOT dependencies, because it tries to download latest version with timestamp that local and remote Maven repository doesn't exist.

**E.g.** I get error like: `"Unresolved dependency com.example.lib:jar:1.0-20130619-143730-688".`

But remote and local repositories don't have this version of library. They have `com.example.lib:jar:1.0-20130619-143730-687` last version.

I don't have this error when I build from command line using `mvn` command.
IDEA points on my M2_HOME Maven installation.

Please, could you help me if faced with the same issue?

Comment: Do you try to clean .m2 folder? Sometimes it helps

Comment: try to clear ~/.IntelliJIdea12/system/Maven/

Comment: Nope. I think this is an extreme solution :)

Comment: Also you can try File->Invalidate Caches... from Intellij.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem configuring maven to import using maven3:

Settings/maven/importing

use maven3 to import project